# Nordic keyboard " < " key switched to " ' "

Tags: keyboard

I started my mac today at work and I got a message saying the mac could not recognize my keyboard. I then had to do a short wizard by typing the key next to <kbd>shift</kbd>.

When I then tried to use the standard <kbd><</kbd> key on my nordic extended mac keyboard, <kbd>'</kbd> gets emitted. It seems like the two has switched places.

How can I make the keyboard behave as it is intended to?

This is the keyboard I have:
[image: Norwegian mac keyboard w/ numpad]

You can see this in the gif below; It starts out as how I want it to be, but if i press any key, the keyboard image in the settings page switch over to the strange layout.

[image: Image from Gyazo]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](https://i.gyazo.com/caedfe8adad69a4c818704a85dd3102c.gif))</sub>

Comment: What does the key under ESC produce?

Comment: It looks like the machine thinks the keyboard is the wrong "type".  See  this note  https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have had a cold. The key under ESC now proudces <. The two keys have just flipped haha.

Comment: Nice article! I will test it at work tomorrow  Thanks!

Comment: I tried all the tips in the article, none helped :/ When I do the Keyboard setup assistant, when I press the key next to shift, it nags saying "Press the key next to shift"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1620325) suggesting me to delete a file

running the following command, then doing a reboot followed by running the assistant again fixed the issue!

```
sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist
```

This was also mentioned in [the article](https://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2009/12/fixing-keyboard-type-problems.html) [@Tom Gewecke](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/49804/tom-gewecke) commented above, but I overlooked it when I did not find the mentioned file in finder. I suppose it might be a hidden file or something.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, the "Change Keyboard Type" feature was absent after upgrading to Ventura, making it impossible for me to redo the key identification. What resolved the issue for me was copying the com.apple.keyboardtype.plist file from my previous installation where it was functioning correctly and replacing the current /Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist file.

Comment: What was the previous installation version that you took the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.keyboardtype.plist` file from? There *might* be compatibility issues with other versions, so knowing what version you used could be useful.